# Gnome extensions in 22.04, windows-list available / not available

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell-extension

I just upgraded both a desktop and a laptop to 22.04 with a clean install using the same USB stick.

Both were default settings installs.

On both machines, I installed Tweak and the Gnome Extensions manager.

On the laptop, under Extensions manager, I found the window-list extension (one I use heavily). It installed and functions as expected.

On the desktop, under Extensions manager, I found the window-list, but it says "unsupported".

When I open the selection to see "supported versions", on the laptop there's a huge list, but on the desktop there's only 3.4 and 3.2 listed. (I think I have 44).

Please, someone make it make sense. SAME installation media, SAME selections on install.

It would be great if someone could tell me how to fix this so I can use the extension.

Thanks.